# Parse tree choices for proving the pumping lemma for CFL

Tags: context-free, pumping-lemma

I was studying pumping lemma for CFL and in the proof it says that, we choose the shortest parse tree if there are multiple parse trees and we also choose $R$ the repeating variable such that it's the lowest in the tree.
It says that it satisfies **condition 2** $(|vy| \gt 0)$ & **3** $(|vxy| \leq p)$. I don't understand how.

Comment: Please don't assume everybody in the world is using the same textbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the book "Introduction to the Theory of Computation, 3rd Edition" by Michael Sipser, he provides arguments for why two conditions follow( you can check theorem 2.34). Additionally, he mentions these arguments in his online lectures, which can be found here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IycOPFmEQk8.

Essentially, the reasoning behind the two conditions is as follows:

The choice of repeating R as the lowest is made to guarantee the fulfillment of the third condition. This choice ensures that the border word remains minimal. If the border word were any larger, it would result in another repetition,  because if the border word were any larger it would give us another repetition, so bottom 2 would've changed(your chosen lowest 2 won't be lowest 2),

Also he argues that opting for the smallest parse tree guarantees the fulfillment of the second condition. If it (vy) were empty, it would imply the existence of a smaller parse tree, contradicting the condition requiring the parse tree to be minimal.